# Accessing map values in a vector in Lemon Graph Library

Tags: c++, lemon-graph-library

i have the following code

```
typedef ListDigraph::NodeMap<string> Node_names;
vector<ListDigraph::Node> initial_state;
vector<Node_names*> P_names;
//some loop
{
   Node_names name;
   ListDigraph::Node state = graph.addNode();
   initial_state = state;
   name[state] = "state1";
   P_names.push_back(&name);
}

void printin()
{
    cout<<P_names[0][initial_state[0]]
}
```

In printin i get the error :

```
error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘((Translator*)this)->Translator::Process_state_name.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = lemon::DigraphExtender<lemon::ListDigraphBase>::NodeMap<std::basic_string<char> >*, _Alloc = std::allocator<lemon::DigraphExtender<lemon::ListDigraphBase>::NodeMap<std::basic_string<char> >*>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference = lemon::DigraphExtender<lemon::ListDigraphBase>::NodeMap<std::basic_string<char> >*&, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int](0u)[((Translator*)this)->Translator::Process_initial_state.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = lemon::ListDigraphBase::Node, _Alloc = std::allocator<lemon::ListDigraphBase::Node>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference = lemon::ListDigraphBase::Node&, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int](0u)]’
```

how do i access the names for the states....

Comment: What's the definition of `Node_name`? If it's a `Node_names`, you're going to need to look at `ListDigraph::NodeMap` or its documentation.

Comment: Node_names is a NodeMap for mapping a node to a name....

Comment: Yes but what is `Node_Name`?

Comment: oh..sorry ...my fault..i edited it to the right version

Comment: Are you using [this library](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon/wiki/Documentation)?

Comment: yess..i m using this library

Comment: does `P_names[0]["test"]` compile (it may not run but that's not the point)?

Comment: What is the *full* error message? You have elided important information which we need to help you.

Comment: i included the full error now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to display `P_names[0][...]` or something like that. Your `Node_names` is a **define**, you probably cannot use the angle brackets like that. Think of it like if you removed your typedef, you would have to write it like that: `ListDigraph::NodeMap<string>[0][P_names[0]]`. Would that make sense?

We can't really help you more if you don't provide more information I'm afraid...

Edit: try `(*P_names[0])["test"]`, maybe that would do it (providing you have all necessary elements).

One thing you can do though is using as many temp variables as you want. You really need to understand what types are `P_names[0]`, `*P_names[0]`, `(*P_names[0])[...]` etc. Try to compile the code, write class names on a paper, have a look at [some diagrams in the documentation](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/pub/doc/latest/a00277.html), draw diagrams (with a pencil on paper), **anything that could help you understand what is going on**.

You are using a library that is not well known and even if people here are trying to help you it is really hard, especially without the code or even worse with a code which is not the actual code...

Comment: but p_names[0] refers to a map object and initial_state[0] refers to a vertex in graph....if normally we had a map object say ..g and vertex object v...then g[v]  would have worked...but why is p_names[0][initial_state[0]] giving error... Also hw can ListDigraph::NodeMap<string>[0][P_names[0]] work ?

Comment: I'm not saying it would work, I answered before your edit (or at least published this answer before seeing your edit).

Comment: Yes, it was my fault. I forgot to update the question. P_names is actually storing the pointers to the maps, maybe thats the problem. How do i dereference the pointer so that i can use the functions of that object. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I used cout<<*P_name[0][initial_state[0]] to derefernce ..but it did not work

Comment: @vigenere I updated my answer, if you dereference your pointer, you probably want to add parenthesis like that `(*P_name[0])[...]`